# How to get referral bonus history using Binance API?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I’m using Binance US . And want to extract referral bonus rewards. Website does not allow export. So I decided to use API. I need it for tax purposes. I tried to look up https://github.com/binance-us/binance-official-api-docs i can see trades api but cannot find rewards api. This is an outrage. How am I supposed to file taxes if Binance.us doesn’t allow to export nor does it provide an api for rewards

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this:
https://www.binance.us/en/referral-details
(since Binance seems not to offer rewards API. If you can use this link).

You said the website doesn't allow export, and what do you mean? If this means the site doesn't allow redirection, you can just use embed instead.

If you still want to find the answer about Rewards API, the answer might be **No**.

Comment: The embedded does not have all my rewards. That list is limited.

Comment: You mean that you've used all your queue of rewards?
If so, I think there's no more ways except making another account.. (as I know)
:(